# Queries reported slow when they took less than slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms to execute

Tags: cassandra

In cassandra.yaml file , we see the value
**slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500**

On the client end  the logs report these slow queries the number of times so far.

```
      1 SELECT * FROM audience_member_by_customer_id
      6 SELECT * FROM campaign
    791 SELECT * FROM campaign;
     22 SELECT * FROM qualification

For eg:  SELECT * FROM campaign;
```

As we can see that the logs at the client side indicate that the queries are being reported slow even before 500ms. Here is an example of time.

```
27/03-14:09:49.862 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-2] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 230 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:53.340 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-3] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 184 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:55.598 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-1] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 205 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:55.717 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-3] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 231 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:55.823 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-2] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 193 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:57.738 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-2] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 199 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:57.790 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-1] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 196 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:09:57.894 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-3] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 241 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:10:01.033 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-1] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 212 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
27/03-14:10:01.079 [DEBUG] [cluster1-nio-worker-3] [::] - [cluster1] Query too slow, took 258 ms: SELECT * FROM campaign; [com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.SLOW]
```

Why is this peculiar behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have conflated the driver logs with `slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms`. I can see how it is easy to confuse those two different things.

The slow query logging property `slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms` in `cassandra.yaml` only applies to server-side logging (nodes in the Cassandra cluster). This will trigger logging on the cluster nodes if a query takes longer than the configured timeout.

In contrast, the messages you posted are logged by the driver on the client-side so `slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms` is completely unrelated.

Since the `DEBUG` messages are logged by `QueryLogger`, it indicates to me that your application is using the older Java driver v3 ([v4 uses `RequestLogger` to track slow queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/core/request_tracker/#request-logger)). By default, [the slow query threshold for the driver is 5 seconds](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.11.3/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryLogger.java#L108):

```
  public static final long DEFAULT_SLOW_QUERY_THRESHOLD_MS = 5000;
```

The debug messages you posted range between `184 ms` to `258 ms` which means that the driver is configured with a very low threshold (for example, `100` or `150` milliseconds) so the slow query logging is getting triggered more than usual.

For reference, your application has set a very low threshold with the `QueryLogger`'s `withConstantThreshold()` method. For example:

```
QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder()
    .withConstantThreshold(100)
    .build();
```

For more information, see [Logging query latencies in Java driver v3](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies). Cheers!